# How to search/replace special chars?

Tags: vim, replace

After a copy-paste from Wikipedia into Vim, I get this:

```
  1 A
  2 
  3 [+] Métier agricole<200e> – 44 P • 2 C
  4 [×] Métier de l'ameublement<200e> – 10 P
  5 [×] Métier de l'animation<200e> – 5 P
  6 [+] Métier en rapport avec l'art<200e> – 11 P • 4 C
  7 [×] Métier en rapport avec l'automobile<200e> – 10 P
  8 [×] Métier de l'aéronautique<200e> – 15 P
```

The problem is that **`<200e>`** is only a char.

I'd like to know how to put it in a search/replace (via the **`/`** or **`:`**).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Check the help for `\%u`:

```
                                /\%d /\%x /\%o /\%u /\%U E678

\%d123  Matches the character specified with a decimal number.  Must be
        followed by a non-digit.
\%o40   Matches the character specified with an octal number up to 0377.
        Numbers below 040 must be followed by a non-octal digit or a non-digit.
\%x2a   Matches the character specified with up to two hexadecimal characters.
\%u20AC Matches the character specified with up to four hexadecimal
        characters.
\%U1234abcd     Matches the character specified with up to eight hexadecimal
        characters.
```

These are sequences you can use. Looks like you have two bytes, so `\%u200e`
should match it. Anyway, it's pretty strange. 20 in UTF-8 / ASCII is the space
character, and 0e is ^N. Check your encoding settings.

Comment: `\u200e` is never encoded as `\x20\x0e` in utf-8, it is encoded as *three* bytes `\xE2\x80\x8E`, you can test this by running `echo "\u200E" is# "\xE2\x80\x8E"`: it will output 1 if you have 'encoding' option equal to 'utf-8'. So, this sequence has no connection with space or newline.

Comment: Thanks @ZyX , much clearer now. I should dedicate a moment to learn more about UTF-8, I'm often facing these here and there without really understanding it. If you know any document that is a must read in this subject please let me know.

Comment: @ZyX by the way I think the real encoding for `\u202E` is `\xE2\x80\xAE` instead (I begin to see a little now)

Comment: UTF-8 is described in wikipedia, there also must be some links, including link to the RFC (I read only Russian version and didn’t bother myself to remember much of it). You can always get how specific symbol is encoded by doing `echo "\u202E"[0] "\u202E"[1] ... "\u202E"[len("\u202E")-1]` or automate it using `let s="\u202E" | echo map(range(len(s)), 's[v:val]')`.

Comment: @sidyll My favorite link on that stuff, I'm still re-reading it almost every 6 months! http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @OlivierPons Thank you for sharing it, really nice article!

Comment: How can I replace <80> and <8a> with ä and Ä in Vim?

Answer (score 5):

1. replace `^@`

   `:%s/\%x00//g`
2. replace `^L`

   // Enter the ^L using ctrl-V ctrl-L

   `:%s/^L//g`

refers:

- [gvim - How to remove this symbol "^@" with vim? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/75130/how-to-remove-this-symbol-with-vim)
- [vim - Deleting form feed ^L characters - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236143/deleting-form-feed-l-characters)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to quickly select this extraneous character everywhere and replace it / get rid of it, you could:

1. isolate one of the strange characters by adding a space before and after it, so it becomes a "word"
2. use the <kbd>*</kbd> command to search for the word under the cursor. If you have `set hlsearch` on, you should then see all of the occurrences of the extraneous character highlighted.
3. replace last searched item by something else, globally:
   `:%s//something else/`