# Deleting form feed ^L characters

Tags: vim

How to delete all form feed characters (represented by ^L) in GVim on Windows?

Answer (score 24):

```
:%s/^L//g
```

will do it. Enter the `^L` using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>

[Here's a guide](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/8255-vim-tips-the-basics-of-search-and-replace) to basic search/replace using Vim.

Comment: Meh, I'm pretty familiar with search and replacing stuff in Vim, but sometimes when I'm doing something else, I just can't seem to remember some things. Currently doing something else :)

Comment: What if you can't use control characters in the pattern?

The substitution needs to be stored in a file and control characters can't be used.  I looked though the help pages and couldn't find anything that worked without using an actual control character in the pattern.