# Search for ~ (tilde) in vim

Tags: search, vim, tilde

How can I search for a <kbd>~</kbd> (tilde) in vim?

I tried `/\~` and `/ \~` as `/~` does not work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8447640/733637) in [vim: how to search/replace special chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447561/vim-how-to-search-replace-special-chars), possibly it applies to your problem, too.

Comment: `/\~` works here and `/[~]` should work too

Comment: @Kent Thanks! Works on my machine with the `/[~]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`/\~` works here. (with `magic` as default)

There are other ways,

- you can search by character class: `/[~]`
- you can search in `nomagic` mode `/\M~`
- you can search in `very nomagic` mode `/\V~`